# How replace String in the XWPFTableCell of docx

Tags: apache-poi

I'm reading a docx file with apache-poi. In the wordfile i need replace every keys equals ${key}. When this key is in paragraph i able to, but i have an situation where my key is in then table of docx and thus, i need iterate the array values in position this key, for example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApMrX.png)

follows the tree of elements

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i62AY.png)

Any idea how i did to interact the values below that keys.

Comment: Add your code to your question so that we can help find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, i have in the doc a cell of paragraph that has 2 fields, RG: and CPF: My second line done but my first line didn't

```
while (tcell.getParagraphs().size() > 1) {
    tcell.removeParagraph(1);
}
XWPFParagraph p = tcell.getParagraphs().get(0);
if (p.getRuns().size() > 0) {
    p.removeRun(0);
    String[] lines = value.split("\n");
    p.createRun().setText(lines[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
        p.getRuns().get(0).addBreak();  
        p.getRuns().get(0).setText(lines[i]);
    }
} else { 
    tcell.setText(value);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDxBo.png)